# Is the iOS 5 beta no longer usable?

Tags: ios, developer-program

I've been using iOS5 beta 7 for a while.  About 4 hours ago (possibly the end of the 20th, PST, the expiration date for iOS 5 beta 7) the phone locked itself and claims it requires activation.  Whenever I try, it claims the activation server is temporarily unavailable.

Should I sit tight and wait, or is there something else I can do, such as wipe iOS5 and reinstall from a release image?

Comment: How about installing iOS 5 GM?

Comment: How about making an actual answer, instead of a comment, Dave :).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Normally, questions about pre release software are off topic for this site. Since this is likely to be useful to many people and not change quickly, I'm leaving this question open. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to upgrade to the release version, not much else you can do about it.

Comment: iTunes insisted my version is up to date, so I tried the factory reset method, after which iTunes admitted it needs to download an update.  I'm 2 hours into the 4 hour download...

Comment: Same here, but with my iPad....

Comment: iTunes won't automatically update the betas - to iTunes, beta 7 is the final version. You need to manually download it from developer.apple.com, or do a restore and download it that way.

Comment: With the download complete, the release version installed fine and my phone is working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

if your iPhone refuses to being updated to iOS 5.0, maybe you should put it in DFU (Device Firmware Update mode). To do that, follow these instructions:

- Plug your iPhone to your Mac/PC;
- Hold the **power button** for 2 seconds;
- Without releasing the power button, hold the **home button** for 10 seconds
- Release the **power button** and keep holding the **home button** until your iPhone appears in iTunes;
- Proceed with software restore; you might restore your software backup at the end of the procedure.

Comment: It looks like the OP knows how to restore and is asking _whether_ to do that. Your answer is technically correct, but doesn't appear to be answering the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

The only beta still usable is the GM. So try updating to this beta.

Comment: GMs aren't betas. That's why they are called Gold Masters.