# iPhone 4 locked out while on holiday, how can I unlock it?

Tags: iphone, ios

I arrived in Greece yesterday and suddenly this morning my phone turned off, then on again and now it says `Activation Required`. When I unlock it to try and do it, I get the message:

> This device is no registered as part of the iPhone Developer Program.##br####br##If you are a member of the Program, please register your device in the @@url@@

It is registered with the developer program. Is there any way I can fix this remotely? I don't have my computer.

**Update**

I updated my phone via the new non beta iTunes to the new iOS5 as far as I'm aware. I'm pretty sure it just said 5.0. That was a couple of days ago.

Also, I will be able to get to a computer with iTunes, but it won't be mine.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28630/9058 -> install iOS 5 via iTunes

Comment: To follow up on patrix, which version of the OS is installed? Is it an iOS beta? Or the latest version?

Comment: I am actually the question asker, just managed to sign in. I should add that the first screen I get says 'restore completed' despite the fact I didn't do any restore!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Question about pre release software are off topic for this site. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: It's not prerelease it's IOS5!!! Why did you close this you busy body!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you, as a developer, have iOS5 installed? Try [recovering](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/06/24/new-in-ios-5-restoring-from-icloud-backup-shown-on-video-tutorial/) from iCloud?
That is if you have backed up your iPhone using iCloud before of course.

**EDIT**: [Use a random computer to back-up your iPhone](http://www.ehow.com/how_5216813_use-two-iphones-one-computer.html)

Comment: I have but I don't have an option to recover from iCloud. How do I do this? Hard reset?

Comment: Just follow the movies instructions in the given link?

Comment: The problem is not that it can't be restored. It's that it can't be activated. I'm the question asked btw.

Comment: Also, what link?

Comment: question asker*

Comment: Hm, the activation can't be done using iCould I guess. You can take a backup with the laptop you have over there (see the link (light-blue text) in my edit) and do a full recovery using iTunes on the laptop.