# Activation fails on iPad running iOS Beta 7

Tags: ipad, ios

This morning my iPad wanted to activate itself once more and at some point I receive the following message:

> We're unable to complete your activation on my iPad
>
> This device is not registered as part of the iPhone Developer Program. If you are a member of the Program, please register your device in the http://developer.apple.com/iphone/.

I am member of the developer and I have registered this device. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS5 Beta 7 Expired Today, Phone Unusable?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28630/ios5-beta-7-expired-today-phone-unusable)

Comment: Looks like it's related to this problem. It is happening to a lot of dev, since Apple has closed the beta access today.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about pre release software are off topic for this site. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating to the GM. It's the last usable version for the dev's.

Comment: How do I go back to the non dev version of iOS?

Comment: If you have a registered device, you can upgrade to the GM. It's the same version as iOS 5.0, so you won't notice a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to the GM  Betas are just that, betas, and Apple has them expire over time to prevent their longterm use.

To update from the Beta 7 to the GM, either:

1) Restore your device via iTunes. iTunes will automatically download the proper build and install it.

2) Download the proper GM release from developer.apple.com.

It is not possible to upgrade from the betas to the GM. Make sure your phone is backed up beforehand, either via iTunes or iCloud. Once you complete the restore, you can restore from the backup to get your data and apps back.